# Invalid bracketing in insert to excel  command using c# and oledb?

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I am iserting some records to excel file using OLEDB

```
    foreach (TblSample rec in LstTblSample)
            {

                OleDbCommand cmdInsert = new OleDbCommand("insert into [sd$]" +
                                                   "([Lab Ref],[D.M.],PH,CP,ADF,NDF,DMD,ME,NIRASH,IFCOW,IFSHEEP,NH3,UFV,UFL,PDIE,PDIN,PDIA,LFU,CFU,SFU) values" +
                                                   "(" + "'" + rec.SampleNo + "'" + "," + "'" + rec.DryMatter + "'" + "," + "'" + rec.pH + "'" + "," +
                                                   "'" + rec.CrudeProtein + "'" + "," + "'" + "" + "'" + "," + "'" + rec.NDF + "'" + "," + "'" + rec.DMD + "'" + "," +
                                                   "'" + rec.ME + "'" + "," + "'" + rec.ASH + "'" + "," + "'" + rec.DMIntakeCattle + "'" + "," +
                                                   "'" + rec.DMIntakeSheep + "'" + "," + "'" + rec.NH3 + "'" + "," + "'" + rec.UFV + "'" + "," +
                                                   "'" + rec.UFL + "'" + "," + "'" + rec.PDIE + "'" + "," + "'" + rec.PDIN + "'" + "," + "'" + rec.PDIA + "'" + "," +
                                                   "'" + rec.LFU + "'" + "," + "'" + rec.CFU + "'" + "," + "'" + rec.SFU + "'" + ")", con);
                cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

My excel file has a column named D.M. which is causing this error. I want to keep this column name in excel because, its used by another software. Is there any work around in C# code for insert to cope with this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where I see a problem is the keyword `values` in this line

```
OleDbCommand cmdInsert = new OleDbCommand("insert into [sd$] values" +
```

In the [`INSERT`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) statement you usually specify the column fields before calling `VALUES`. Alternatively you can call `VALUES` without naming the column fields. In this instance you do both. Above `VALUES` BEFORE assigning the columns causes a problem.

One option is to remove the column declaration completely and just do `insert into [sd$] values                                                   "(" + "'" + rec.SampleNo +` - i.e. is the columns and entries match. You can also try rename the column in the INSERT statement to [DM] and then after the data was inserted rename the column in the excel spreadsheet to [D.M.] as a routine task using the following code modifying it of course: http://dontbreakthebuild.com/2012/03/16/reading-excel-column-names-in-c-using-excel-interop/

If all else fails make use of the [Open XML SDK 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) to try and manipulate the document.

I'm out! Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, that was a error in my copy paste. I have that correctly in my actual application. I still get that error