# OleDbCommand use brackets '[' ']' in a query as table name

Tags: c#, oledb, sql-insert, oledbcommand

I have a `Excel` file which contains the following column names: `name`,`Display name [de-DE]`,`Comment [de-DE]`.

[image]

If I use this query, `Insert into [foo$] ([Name],[Display name [de-DE]],[Comment [de-DE]]`, I get an `exception:`.

> Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

How do I have to escape the `brackets` to use them in the query?

## sample code

```cs
var connectionString = $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\"{Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "foo.xlsx")}\";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\"";

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        try
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = @"Insert into [Hmi Tags$] ([Name],[Display name [de-DE]],[Comment [de-DE]]) 
                                VALUES ('foo1','foo2','foo3');";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("success");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}


Console.ReadKey();
```

## workaround

The only working solution so far is based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12499797/6229375

> One option is to remove the column declaration completely and just do `insert into..`

Comment: Try this: `[Display name [de-DE]]]` or that: `[Display name [[de-DE]]]`

Comment: sadly does not work

Comment: Maybe this post helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439495/how-can-i-escape-square-brackets-in-a-like-clause

Comment: @Caramiriel I have also tried to answer without success

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Insert into [foo$] ('[Name]','[Display name [de-DE]]','[Comment [de-DE]]',
```

Comment: @DominicJonas Can you please add your full insert query? exactly what are you using?

Comment: I have added additional infos to my question including sample